# What is a glob in salt-stack?

Tags: deployment, terminology, salt

I was going through targeting minions in salt. There I came across a term called `glob`. Can someone explain with an example what is a **`glob`** in Salt-Stack?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming) explains how this originated in UNIX.  It shows up in lots of places now since UNIX was so influential.

Answer (score 4):

Globbing is a term used for matching file name patterns with wild cards.  You can see a more detailed definition here https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/globbing

As it relates to Salt Stack, it's finding the minion id using wild cards.  Additional details here: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/globbing.html